# Defining the set of natural numbers in the first order Peano arithmetic

Tags: lo.logic, theories-of-arithmetic

The question seems simple, but I'm not sure:
let's consider a first order Peano Arithmetic and its standard model $N = \{ 0,1,2,3,... \}$ of natural numbers.
A question: how can we define the **whole set $N$** by a single formula? I.e. is there a formula $\phi(x)$ such that $PA \vdash \phi(x)$ iff $x \in N$ ?

Comment: Perhaps the OP is looking for the fact that the formula $x=x$ defines the whole domain in any model of PA, or indeed in any model of any theory.

Comment: True, but what I mean is: there is a formula {(0 ∈ N) ∧ (x ∈ N ⟹ (x+1) ∈ N)} which is true **iff** x ∈ N. (provided we explicitly set N as a domain of our model). My question: is there a similar formula in the language of 1st order PA ?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. In the formula $\varphi(x)$ the symbol $x$ is a syntactic symbol, a variable symbol, and it makes no sense to ask whether $x\in\mathbb{N}$, if by that you mean the standard model. You are asking whether you can prove this thing about the variable $x$ if and only if $x$ is an actual number. It's a type mismatch.

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to ask: can we define the standard cut in an arbitrary nonstandard model of PA? In this case, the answer is no, because the set of objects fulfilling that definition would contain $0$ and be closed under successor, but not be the whole model.

Comment: That is closer to my question, thanks. You mean that in any nonstandard model we can't identify the standard cut (coinciding with N) by means of some formula of 1st order PA, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is right. This would violate the induction scheme, since the formula would fulfill the inductive requirement, but it wouldn't define the whole domain.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood the question totally, let me know if I answered, if not I will retry to do so.

Peano Arithmetic does not include sets, maybe you are trying to find a formula such that $ZFC \vdash \phi(x)$ iff $x \in \mathbb{N}$?

In such case there is a formula, we first have to define inductive sets, so we let $I(x)$ ($x$ is inductive) stand for $(\emptyset \in x) \land (\forall y (y \in x \implies y \cup \{y\} \in x))$, then we let $\mathbb{N} = \{y \in J| \forall x(I(x) \implies y \in x)\}$ where $J$ is an inductive set, that exists by the axiom of infinity.

Hence by working backwards on the definitions, we get $(y \in \mathbb{N}) \iff (y \in J \land \forall x(((\emptyset \in x) \land (\forall y (y \in x \implies y \cup \{y\} \in x))) \implies y \in x)$, but $J$ is just a constant symbol that refers to an inductive set, so it is easy to see that $(y \in J \land \forall x(I(x) \implies y \in x)) \iff \forall x(I(x) \implies y \in x)$, hence the formula that defines the naturals is $(y \in \mathbb{N}) \iff \forall x(((\emptyset \in x) \land (\forall z (z \in x \implies z \cup \{z\} \in x))) \implies y \in x)$.

This definition however needs only the axioms of extensionality, comprehension, pairing, union and infinity.

If however you are trying to find a formula that has as its only model the natural numbers, you can't do it, since every isomorphic model will do the trick.
You can however reach a similar result by weakening the request, in fact by asking if you can find a second order formula that has as its only models (the definition change a bit), isomorphic sets of the naturals, the answer is yes, second order arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Let me clarify a bit more. Of course, I don't mean definition of natural numbers "uniquely" in the 1st order PA. I know, this is impossible. We initially set standard N as a model of PA which we consider, so not meaning any non-standard models of PA. My question is: what is a formula ϕ(x) **in the language of 1st order PA** which is provable in it **iff** x∈N ? In other words, how can we express the domain N of 1st order PA in its language as a formula. Your answer looks _almost_ correct  but it is **not in language (signature)** of 1st order PA...

Comment: A bit more clarification: for example, we know how to express odd or even numbers. N is a union of both. Consequently we can express **any** x∈N as "odd **or** even". But is there a more **elegant** and natural way? ... involving just successor function and induction?

Comment: The formula $x=x$, or indeed any tautological statement, defines the whole domain in any model.

Comment: @Joel David. True :), but what I'm interested in is more a question of the language (representability) of the 1st order PA: can we express the formula (0 ∈ N) ∧ (x ∈ N ⟹ (x+1) ∈ N) in the language of the 1st order PA?